# Is it possible to Conditionally Count & Add row labels in MySQL?

Tags: mysql, sql

I have a data set

```
HAPPY
1
0
0
0
0
1
1
```

I would like to count the 1s and 0s to return

```
Status | Count
YES    | 3
NO     | 4
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
select if (HAPPY=1, 'YES', 'NO') as Status,
    count(HAPPY) as Count from Table1 group by HAPPY order by Status desc;
```